# Prove that the function integer part is continuous for any topology in Z.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Prove that the function integer part $f:\mathbb{R}_l \to \mathbb{Z}, \quad f(x) =\lfloor x \rfloor $ is continuous for any topology in $\mathbb{Z}$.

where $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the topology of the lower limit in $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that if I prove that it is continuous in a finer topology in $\mathbb{Z},$ that is to say in the discrete topology, then it will be continuous in all topologies. But I can't prove it as the reverse image will be. I will appreciate your comments.

Comment: Note that the fibers of the map, aka sets of the form $[n,n+1)$, are open in the lower limit topology. This implies that the function is continuou.

Comment: @DonThousand Of course, I don't know how I could ignore it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that for any set $A \subseteq \mathbb Z$ we have $f^{-1}(A)=\cup_{n \in A} [n, n+1)$ which is open.